# I tried to install Netflix on Ubuntu 20.04 and now it gives me some errors

Tags: apt

whenever I try `sudo apt-get update` it give me an error. Here is what it says. (including the download).

```
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-fonville/android-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:5 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease        
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Hit:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:8 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file) `ehoover/compholio` repository is dead. They last updated their repository for 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu focal InRelease
```

- Was Ign(Ignored) Because this repository does not have a Release file.
- thare is no isue with **Netflix**.
- You need to remove repository. Follow below commands to remove.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo apt auto-remove
sudo apt update
```

- Now, You don't face that error again :)

Comment: Thank you soo much you have helped me a lot.